# how to get overall score with strange rules

Tags: r

I have a sample data that looks like this:

[image]

Each ID have 2 subject test: test1 and test2. Overall test result is come from two subject tests. If I want to calculate each ID's final test result following the rule:

if one's subject test results has one P, then his test result is P;
if One's subject test results has N, not P, then his test result is N;
if One's subject test results are all N/A, then is N/A.
If one's test 1 and 2's final results has P, his overall result is P,
If one's test 1 and 2's final results are all N, then his overall result is N;
If one's test 1 and 2's final results has N/A and not P, then his overall is N/A;
Is it a way to calculate overall test result neatly. How can I achieve this goal.
I think i need to build a new variable for overall_test1 and overall_test2 and then calculate overall. New to R and not sure how to deal with letters.

The outcome should be something that looks like this:

[image]

The sample data can get from following codes:

```
ID <-c("1", "1", "1","2", "2","3", "3", "3")
Test_date <-c("2020-07-09", "2020-07-19","2020-07-29", "2020-07-07","2020-07-18","2020-07-09", "2020-07-19","2020-07-29")
Test1 <-c("N/A","P","N","N/A", "N","N","N/A", "N")
Test2<-c("N/A","P","P","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A", "N") 
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Test_date, Test1, Test2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you're going to need to use string detection.

Try this:

```
final_classifications = 
  Sample.data %>% 
  mutate(
    Test1 = str_replace(Test1, "N/A", "Z"),
    Test2 = str_replace(Test2, "N/A", "Z")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(P = (any(str_detect(Test1, 'P'))),
         N = (any(str_detect(Test1, 'N'))),
         overall_1 = ifelse(P == "TRUE", "P", 
                            ifelse(N == "TRUE", "N", "N/A")),
         P2 = (any(str_detect(Test2, 'P'))),
         N2 = (any(str_detect(Test2, 'N'))),
         overall_2 = ifelse(P2 == "TRUE", "P", 
                            ifelse(N2 == "TRUE", "N", "N/A")),
         overall = ifelse(overall_1 == "P" | overall_2 == "P", "P",
              ifelse(overall_1 == "N/A" | overall_2 == "N/A", "N/A", "N"))
         ) %>% 
  select(ID, overall) %>% 
  unique()
```

I replace "N/A" with "Z" in the first mutate step to avoid picking up "N/A" cells with the str_detect when I'm looking for "N". There may be a more direct way to avoid this.

Comment: overall_test1 need to get from test1 by ID.  One ID has multiple test1 results. basically we can get a  new data set which only have 3 row (Id=1, 2, 3) and each one has 1 overall_test1, overall_test2, overall.  Overall won't be able to get directly from one row of test1 and test2.

Comment: Understood - I've updated my answer to hopefully better answer the question.